# Pass string from UITableView to UIView in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfielddelegate

I want to pass 2 string selected from UITableview (CompleteView) to new UIView (DetailView)
This is my code:

In CompleteView.h()

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *memoString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *previewString;
```

In Completeview.m()

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{           
previewString = [PreviewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"Preview string %@",previewString);
            memoString = [MemoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"Memo string %@",memoString);

            DetailView *detailAlert = [[DetailView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 300, 300)];
            detailAlert.strPreview =previewString ;
            detailAlert.strMemo =  memoString;

            [self.view addSubview:detailAlert];
            [detailAlert show];
            [detailAlert release];
}
```

In DetailView()

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        originalFrame = frame;

        UIWebView *videoview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,80,275.0,150)];
        NSString *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strPreview];
        NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
        [videoview loadRequest:nsrequest];
        [self addSubview:videoview];

    return self;
}
```

In DetailView.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* strMemo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* strPreview;
```

When run, previewString not send to DetailView. I'm debug, when run strPreview and strMemo in DetailView is 0x00000. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your problem ? code is correct

Comment: When run, previewString not send to DetailView. I'm debug, when run strPreview and strMemo in DetailView is 0x00000

Comment: @NGOT see DharaParekh's Code and now try it.

Comment: for NSString - property you should use "copy" attribute instead of retain. try make to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass custom Initialisers like below . If you wish you can add one parameter
to  custom Initialisers

In CompleteView.h()

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *memoString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *previewString;
```

In Completeview.m()

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{           
previewString = [PreviewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"Preview string %@",previewString);
            memoString = [MemoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"Memo string %@",memoString);

            DetailView *detailAlert = [[DetailView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 300, 300) andPreviewstring:previewString];
            detailAlert.strPreview =previewString ;
            detailAlert.strMemo =  memoString;

            [self.view addSubview:detailAlert];
            [detailAlert show];
            [detailAlert release];
}
```

In DetailView()

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andPreviewstring:(NSString *)stPreview
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        originalFrame = frame;

        UIWebView *videoview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,80,275.0,150)];
        NSString *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strPreview];
        NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
        [videoview loadRequest:nsrequest];
        [self addSubview:videoview];

    return self;
}
```

In DetailView.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* strMemo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* strPreview;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andPreviewstring:(NSString *)stPreview;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {           
    previewString = [PreviewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Preview string %@",previewString);
    memoString = [MemoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Memo string %@",memoString);

    DetailView *detailAlert = [[DetailView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 300, 300)];
    detailAlert.strPreview =previewString ;
    detailAlert.strMemo =  memoString;
    [detailAlert createWebView];

    [self.view addSubview:detailAlert];
    [detailAlert show];
    [detailAlert release];
```

}

write code for string allocation

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        originalFrame = frame;

        //add following two lines
        strPreview = [[NSString alloc] init];
        strMemo = [[NSString alloc] init];
        //........
        return self;
}

-(void) createWebView {
    UIWebView *videoview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,80,275.0,150)];
    NSString *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strPreview];
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [videoview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self addSubview:videoview];
}
```

Comment: @NGOT  what is the nslog output for this three lines.   NSLog(@"Preview string %@",previewString);
memoString = [MemoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Memo string %@",memoString);

Comment: if NSLog, in COmpleteView show value of 2 variable previewString and memoString, but when push DetailView (UIVIew type), 2 variable is not show value

Comment: @NGOT see my edited answer... check it and after that I explain the bug to you

Comment: in your code, problem is... 1) DetailView *detailAlert = [[DetailView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 300, 300)];   you write this line. so, the initWithFrame of DetailView is called. and in this method you use the two string objects for webview right? but originally you pass your two strings after that this method calling is complete. your this two line detailAlert.strPreview =previewString ;
    detailAlert.strMemo =  memoString; executed after initWithFrame method is complete and you use strPreview, strMemo in initWithFrame method. so, it has no value

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are setting two properties in detail view after initializing DetailView. But you are trying to use a property values within the initializer which are yet to be set.

As I can see there are two options you can try out.

1. Write another initializer which accept these two properties. So that you can use those two properties in that initializer.

   - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame strMemo:(NSString *)memo strPreview:(NSString *)preview {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
         originalFrame = frame;

     ```
     UIWebView *videoview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,80,275.0,150)];
     NSString *url=[NSURL URLWithString:preview];
     NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
     NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
     [videoview loadRequest:nsrequest];
     [self addSubview:videoview];

     return self;
     ```

     }
2. Or else you can extract the logic in the current initializer and put them in to a separate method which you can called after setting two properties from the CompleteView.